# Azure resources query including multiple tags returns an error

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-monitor

Hollo, there!

Tried to query Azure resources filtering by Tag info (configuration is written in yaml). The aim of the query is to retrieve resource metrics information, providing multiple tags in query string.

```
- resource_query: tagName eq 'tagname1' and tagValue eq 'tagvalue1' and tagName eq 'tagname2' and tagValue eq 'tagValue2'
```

However, this query returns errror message, stating that "Status=400 Code="InvalidFilterInQueryString""

Is there any other approach to query resources providing multiple tags in configuration?

Tried to query using only one Tag

```
- resource_query: tagName eq 'tagname1' and tagValue eq 'tagvalue1'
```

it works, but when there are multiple it fails.

Comment: Can you share the complete query to resolve the issue. @Sintija Bukša

Answer (score 0):

> Azure resources query including multiple tags returns an error: -

Running a query using `and` operator will fail because a resource cannot have two tags with the same name according to your requirement.

Instead use the `or` operator to query the resources with multiple tags.

Modify your query as:

```bash
- resource_query: (tagName eq 'tagname1' and tagValue eq 'tagvalue1') or (tagName eq 'tagname2' and tagValue eq 'tagValue2')
```

Now this query returns resources with `tagname1=tagvalue1` or `tagname2=tagValue2`.

*I ran a sample query to check the above functionality in Azure resource graph explorer as I don't have an `yaml` file of data and was successful as shown.*

```bash
resources
| where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'
| mvexpand tags
| extend tagKey = tostring(bag_keys(tags))
| extend tagValue = tostring(tags[tagKey])
| where tagKey contains  "ClusterId"  and tagValue contains  ""  or tagKey contains  "Owner"  and tagValue contains  ""
| project resourceGroup
```

[image]